# Return a dynamic array based on SQL

Tags: java, jdbc

I would like to create a method that returns an array with all the values from the database.

This is what I have so far:

```
package ch.test.zt;

import java.sql.*;

class Database {

    static boolean getData(String sql) {
        // Ensure we have mariadb Driver in classpath
        try {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/zt_productions?user=root&password=test";

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            return rs.next();

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

That means, I could use `Database.getData("SELECT * FROM users")` and I get an array with all the data from the database that I need.

In my code above I am using `return rs.next();`, which is definitely wrong. That returns `true`.

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? Have you read the JavaDocs of [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html)?

Answer (score 1):

rs.next(); just tell whether your result set has data in it or not i.e true or false , in order to use or create array of the actual data , you have to iterate over your result set and create a user object from it and have to add that object in your users list

Also change the signature

```
 static List<User> getData(String sql)
```

And best to use like `Select Username,UserId from Users; as your  sql`
something like this:

```
   try {    List<User> userList = new ArrayLisy();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            //until there are results in the resultset loop over it
             while (rs.next()) {              
               User user = new User();
               user.SetName(rs.getString("username"));
               // so on.. for other fields like userID ,age , gender ,loginDate,isActive  etc ..
               userList.add(user);
            } 
          }
```

when you don't know about the columns of the table you are going to fetch then you can find the same using :

Now you know all the information then you can construct a proper query using it
and work from this

```
  DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet resultSet = metadata.getColumns(null, null, "users", null);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
          String name = resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
          String type = resultSet.getString("TYPE_NAME");
          int size = resultSet.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");

          System.out.println("Column name: [" + name + "]; type: [" + type + "]; size: [" + size + "]");
        }
      }
```

Comment: Well, that's not really dynamic. What if I don't know the column names like username, userID etc.?